# React App with Firebase authentication via LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, react-context

I'm creating a REACT + Firebase CRUD application, with an initial login route and some other private routes related to the CRUD functionality, only available for authenticated and authorized users.

To perform the login, I use the Firebase *signInWithEmailAndPassword* method, providing the login + password as inputs and getting an authentication token as a return.

Afterwards, I store this token in my *LocalStorage*. Whenever a private route is called, a Token validity check is called, in a fashion as follows:

```
//Private Route component
const RoutesPrivate = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  
  //Get token from 'StoreContext' context to validate user session
  const { userToken } = useContext(UserTokenContext);

  //Check Token validity before redirecting to private route
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => validateToken(userToken)
        ? <Component {...rest} />
        : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  )
}
```

So, the **validateToken(userToken)** method calls a back-end specific route to check the token validity. If the token is valid and up to date, it returns TRUE, and allow the Private Route to be loaded. If not, it returns FALSE.

**The question is - is this approach safe? If not, how should I change it? Which approach to adopt?**

Other important thing is that all the CRUD operations in the Private Routes via the back-end server (Firebase Admin) are validated again using the stored token, so even if an invader manages to get in a private route without a token (bypassing the validateToken conditional someway), he will not be able to load any data or submit anything (all the requests check the token before doing anything - GET, POST, PUT). The token is used both to allow the access to the private route in a first step, and afterwards to validate any REST request inside the private zone.

Thanks for the support, and sorry for the lack of knowledge - still evolving in this part, willing to choose the best approach.

Comment: I am not sure it is perfect from a security perspective, but I am using similar to you.

Comment: Yeah, in fact I don't know if this is the best approach, but seems at least reasonable. As I'm just starting the project, there's time to change if there are best ways to do it. Waiting for some experienced feedback to add to this discussion.